# Get number of descendants at each node in tree in linear time without dynamic programming?

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I have written a recursive function that computes the number of descendants at each node in an n-ary tree. 
The results of the computation are in the array that is passed in. I am looking for a function that runs in linear time and does not use dynamic programming. The results would ideally be set within each node not requiring a separate data structure. Recursive is preferred if possible.

```
void setNumberDescendants(Node root, int[] descCount) {                                        
    for(Node child:root.children){
       setNumberDescendants(child, descCount);
       descCount[root.key] += 1+descCount[child.key];
    }        
} 

class Node{
    int key;    
    List<Node> children;     
}
```

Comment: Your own solution does exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution does what you ask for.

**It is linear:** you only access each node once, and do a constant amount of work for each one.

**It does not use dynamic programming:** dynamic programming requires a problem to exhibit overlapping subproblems and optimal substructure. This problem does not exhibit overlapping subproblems. Your subproblems, for a set node, consist of the answers for the subtrees rooted at that node. These subtrees do no overlap.

If you want to set the results in each node, simply do something like this:

```
void setNumberDescendants(Node root) {                                        
    for(Node child:root.children){
       setNumberDescendants(child);
       root.descendants += 1+child.descendants;
    }        
} 

class Node{
    int key;   
    int descendants; 
    List<Node> children;     
}
```

Comment: I had misunderstood "overlapping subproblems." I had thought it meant any subproblems overlap, but if it must be "for a set node," I understand my error.

Comment: @lf215 - you can think about it like this: if a direct recursive implementation of the solution will compute the same thing multiple times, the problem exhibits overlapping subproblems, otherwise it does not. For example, take fibonacci: `f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2)`. If you implement this recursion directly, `f(n)` will compute `f(n - 2)`, then `f(n - 1)` will compute `f(n - 1 - 1) = f(n - 2)`, which is the same thing. So we have overlapping subproblems here. In your case, this doesn't happen.

Comment: Yes, I read that as soon as you posted your answer and understood. My  error was due to my thinking that the initial 'problem' was computing the no. of descendants for each node. (A naive impl could be n^2 by traversing the tree downwards for each node.) If this is the problem, then 2 subproblems, could be counting descendants of the root and counting the descendants of a diff node, 'x'. Therefore, these 2 subproblems necessarily overlap. But my 'problem' was really to count descendants at a given node and due to the solution's recursive impl, it ends up counting desc at each node.